# Conditional Expectation for Large Population

Tags: conditional-expectation

This was another question on my past exam and I'm curious to kmow how to solve it.

Let there be a population of 100,000 and the chance of someone being infected with a certain disease is 0.000001.

Let X be the number of infected people.
Find: 
1. E[X] (Equals 1)
2. E[X| One person is observed to be infected]
3. E[X|Two people are observed to be infected]

Comment: For the latter two, do you mean at least one and at least two? Otherwise, the answers are just 1 and 2.

Comment: It said exactly one and exactly two. As if you were physically inspecting them all, you see one and then want to know how many more you should expect given you found this one.

Comment: If you inspected them *all* and found 1, you know there's exactly 1.